# Make a Javascript equivalent of a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a DOM element in a web page. I want to make JavaScript file that I can use to create such a DOM element in another web page.

This is just a one time conversion (that I probably will do several times, though ;-) ). So I just need something I can use in the JavaScript console.

I will handle styles separately (except for inline styles).

Has someone perhaps already done something like that?

*UPDATE* I want to use it to create a copy later in a totally different web page. I want to use document.createElement etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the basic serialization facilities provided by the DOM are what you need. That is: serialize what you need using `outerHTML` and then deserialize it with `innerHTML` on the receiving side.

Suppose this HTML:

```
<div id="origin">
  <p id="foo">This is a test <a href="#">blah</a></p>
  <p>We skip this</p>
  <p id="bar">Another para.</p>
</div>
<div id="dest">
</div>
```

The `div` with id `origin` is our simulated origin, the `div` with id `dest` is the simulated destination. In our simulation here, they are in the same document, but the code *will* work with an origin and destination that are different DOM trees.

Now the following JavaScript, which I've commented to explain what it does:

```
// Code for the origin side...

// The elements to grab.
var elems = [document.getElementById("foo"), 
             document.getElementById("bar")];

// A buffer to hold all the HTML...
var buf = [];
for (var i = 0; (elem = elems[i]); ++i)
    buf.push(elem.outerHTML);

// Serial contains the HTML of all the elements.
var serial = buf.join('');
console.log(serial);

// Above this point is what would run on the origin side. 
// And below is what would run on the destination side.

// It can be added to the destination DOM just like this...
var dest = document.getElementById("dest");
dest.innerHTML = serial;

//
// A more complicated scenario where the various nodes might need to go 
// in different places on the basis of the `id` attribute they have, could do this:
//
// var container = document.createElement("div");
// container.innerHTML = serial;

// var child = container.firstChild;
// while (child) {
//    // You have to grab the next node **before** moving the
//    // current one.
//    var next = child.nextSibling;
//
//    var id = child.id;
//
//    // ... Find where to put it on the basis of the id and add it to the DOM...
//
//    child = next;
// }
```

The code above takes the paragraphs with ids `foo` and `bar` and copies them from the source to the destination.

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k74e6uxe/1/) illustrating how it works.

My example above is bare-bones. In a situation in which you need to record information together with the elements (maybe because the final location in the destination DOM depends on the location in the origin DOM, for instance) , you could create a JSON structure to hold an array of objects like:

```
{ location .. where this element came from ...,
  html: .. the value of `outerHTML` for the element }
```

and use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to pass the whole structure from origin to destination.

Comment: Thanks Louis, I thought first that this can not work (and that is why I asked this question), but when I got to the bottom of your answer I saw "JSON". I think JSON.stringify will take take of the naste escaping problem. I have to test. ;-)

Comment: It works nicely using JSON. I added my code as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can to do like this

```
var impl    = document.implementation,
    xmlDoc  = impl.createDocument(namespaceURI, qualifiedNameStr, documentType),
    htmlDoc = impl.createHTMLDocument(title);

and it for old IEs

var htmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("htmlfile");
```

Comment: Thanks vcrzy, but I want to save the JavaScript code and use it later in another web page.

Answer (score 0):

```
something like this
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul id="myList1"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>
<ul id="myList2"><li>Water</li><li>Milk</li></ul>

<p id="demo">Click the button to copy an item from one list to another</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var itm=document.getElementById("myList2").lastChild;
var cln=itm.cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(cln);
}
</script>

<p>Try changing the <em>deep</em> parameter to false, and only an empty LI element will be cloned.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, kki3908050, but I want to use it in another document later. Not at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I took @Louis' suggestion to use innerHTML and JSON. For grabbing the elements I use this that will popup a window with most of the needed JavaScript code:

```
/** Copy nodes from one web page for insertion in a totally different
 * page at another time.
 */
function copyNodes(idList){
    var nodesRec = {};
    function copyAsInnerHTML(id) {
        var elt = document.getElementById(id);
        var cont = elt.innerHTML;
        cont = cont.replace(/^\s*/gm, "");
        nodesRec[id] = [elt.nodeName, cont];
    } 
    for (var i=0, id; id=idList[i++];) {
        copyAsInnerHTML(id);
    }
    js = "insertAll("+JSON.stringify(nodesRec)+");\n\n\n";
    var doc = window.open("", "_blank").document;
    var div = doc.createElement("div");
    var txt = doc.createTextNode(js);
    div.appendChild(txt);
    doc.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

The rest of the JavaScript code for adding/replacing the elements goes like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    function insertAll(recAll) {
        function insertThis(key, rec) {
            var type = rec[0];
            var cont = rec[1];
            var oldElt = document.getElementById(key);
            var elt = oldElt || document.createElement(type);
            elt.setAttribute("id", key);
            if (type === "script" || type === "style") {
                elt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cont));
                if (!oldElt) document.head.appendChild(elt);
            } else {
                elt.innerHTML = cont;
                if (!oldElt) document.body.appendChild(elt);
            }
        }
        Object.keys(recAll).forEach(function(key) {
            insertThis(key, recAll[key]);
        });
    }

    // Now copy from above here:
    insertAll({...});

 });
```